How to disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS in Jackson for MultipartFile in Spring Boot?
I am working on a Spring Boot project where I need to send a multipart POST request. However, I am encountering an error related to Jackson serialization:

No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

I do not want to use Base64 encoding for the MultipartFile. Instead, I would like to disable the SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS feature in Jackson.  Here is the relevant part of my code:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.riu.corporate.hr.employeepayrollaggregator.application.exception.HttpRequestException;
import com.riu.corporate.hr.employeepayrollaggregator.domain.port.service.http.post.HttpPostRequestService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class HttpPostRequestServiceImpl implements HttpPostRequestService {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private TokenServiceImpl tokenRequest;

    @Override
    public <T> T sendMultipartPostRequest(String urlString, MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> requestData, Class<T> responseType) throws HttpRequestException {
        try {
            objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
            String bearerToken = tokenRequest.getMachineToMachineToken();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> multipartRequest = requestData;
            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(multipartRequest, headers);

            // Log the cURL command
            StringBuilder curlCommand = new StringBuilder("curl -X POST ");
            curlCommand.append("\"").append(urlString).append("\" ");
            headers.forEach((key, value) -> curlCommand.append("-H \"").append(key).append(": ").append(String.join(", ", value)).append("\" "));
            multipartRequest.forEach((key, value) -> {
                for (MultipartFile file : value) {
                    curlCommand.append("-F \"").append(key).append("=@").append(file.getOriginalFilename()).append("\" ");
                }
            });
            log.info("cURL command: {}", curlCommand.toString());

            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(urlString, requestEntity, String.class);

            if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
                throw new HttpRequestException("Failed to call API: " + response.getStatusCode());
            }

            return objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), responseType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to call API: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new HttpRequestException("Failed to call API", e);
        }
    }
}

Despite disabling the SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS feature, I am still encountering the same error. How can I resolve this issue without using Base64 encoding for the MultipartFile?
I try to use
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);


How do you expect the multipart data to be send? Don't disable features on the global ObjectMapper that will only lead to errors and weird behavior in the rest of your application.

I have two services: one service contains the endpoints, and the other writes employee information. The endpoints work correctly with Postman, but the service that writes employee information throws an error. This service calls the HttpPostRequestService, which creates a multipart request and performs a POST operation. The sendMultipartPostRequest function in this service is causing the error.

That is not an answer to the question. You are sending multipart data which needs to be encoded in someway, that is also what postman does (check the actual request).
